Small AI server with general purpose GPUs
I am planning to start a small project where multiple general-purpose GPUs (a couple of 3060/70/80 or 4060/70/80/90), the idea is that students could use this for their AI workloads.
The choice of GPUs is restricted to general-purpose GPUs (and not AI-specific GPUs) as these are widely available in local market. Assuming no more than 100 students at a time using the service, I want to know

What GPUs should be used regarding price/power/performance?
What tools can be used to estimate the total workload required and set some worst-case scenarios?
What open-source tools can I use for virtualization and setting independent sessions with limited resources for each student?
Any other considerations that I need to keep in mind?


We cannot guess for you what your students are going to do with them. You need to define all of the AI tools and workloads that you want to run so that we can recommend GPUs appropriate for that. With that said, my best guess is that "100 students at a time using the service" and "a couple of [gpus]" doesn't sound like enough compute power. A single GPU could be entirely utilized by one student's AI training. If you virtualize a single GPU to many users it might end up making training times untenable.

Yeah true that is hard to estimate without concrete idea of what the students would be running on the GPUs, I am not very familiar with AI algorithms so I could not draw a worst-case scenario, I was hoping someone could guesstimate that instead based on the fact that students work are generally labs that should run on laptops GPU (mine was NVIDIA 840 ) in less than 2-3 days.
